# ASP.NET vb use databound variable in SQL statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a data repeater that lists accounts in a sql data table. In another tablet is transactions with the account name and an amount for the transaction. I use the following code for the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
       <ItemTemplate>

            <div> <strong><%# Eval("Account")%> </strong></div>
            <div> <%# Eval("Type")%> </div>  

       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Now I want to make another sql statement that will be in each block of the repeater to add the account total (sum of all transactions for that account. I don't know how to format the sql statement. something like:

```
"SELECT SUM(Amount)  FROM Transactions WHERE ([Account] LIKE '%' + @Account + '%')"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to modify the sql stqtement of your SqlDataSource2 to include the "sum of all transactions for that account".
This will give something like this:

```
Select u.Account, u.Type, count(t.Account) as NumberTransactions
From User u inner join Transactions t on u.Account = t.Account
```

I don't know the exact name of your tables so this is just an example.
After that, for your Repeater you have the Account, Type and NumberTransaction from the same datasource.

Comment: Using your select statement as an example, you'll need a GROUP BY

`Select u.Account, u.Type, count(t.Account) as NumberTransactions
From User u inner join Transactions t on u.Account = t.Account  GROUP BY u.Account, u.Type`

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to convey the idea that you can get everything from a single query. Not knowing the names of the tables, my query could only be wrong :)